# Visual Studio: Lost CD

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I have my original CD housing for my copy of Visual Studio 2008 Standard. Therefore I still have my key. I have trial versions of 2008 and 2010, and Express versions of both, but can't find a place to enter my CD key.

What am I suppose to do? I lost my CD. Should I just call MSFT and ask them what to do?

Answer (score 2):

> **To upgrade Visual Studio 2008 Trial
>   Edition**
>
> On the Start menu, click Control
>   Panel.
>
> In Control Panel, open Add or Remove
>   Programs.
>
> Select Microsoft Visual Studio 2008
>   Professional and then click
>   Change/Remove.
>
> On the Visual Studio 2008 Maintenance
>   screen, enter the product key in the
>   section Upgrade to Visual Studio 2008
>   Professional and then click Upgrade.

[Linkage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms246600(VS.80).aspx)

The article is for VS2005 but I've done it a few times with my copy of VS2008.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to get a replacement disk, it looks like [a call to Microsoft's Sales Department will be able to get you started](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vssetup/thread/5b7d8043-33a5-49af-8f83-16ff7b6623cd).

Answer (score 0):

It has to be done manually.

> In this article we will briefly describe how we can change the Visual Studio 2008 product key. As we know Visual Studio 2008 Trial doesn’t allow to change the product key and it shows as grayed out.

http://www.itsolutionskb.com/2009/01/how-to-change-visual-studio-2008-product-key/

Comment: Great link. Unfortunately, there's a "setup.sdb" file required that apparently doesn't exist with the trial version of 2008. Thanks though!